# set up manual Payment method in magento site without buying products

Tags: paypal, payment-methods

please visit this link : https://atl-54197f5e5c91d.secure.myob.net/payonline

Here, there is an option for payment method without buying products.

here after completing the 1st step : "Invoice Details", 2nd and 3rd step have to complete.

for me only 1st step is enough. after clicking "Enter Payment Details", it should link to " paypal website" .

how to set up this payment system in magento site.

let me know if you need any clarifications.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way around it could be to create a product using the Gift Card product type, and on prices set 'Allow Open Amount' to yes. This way you can have a product called 'Pay Invoice', so that the customer adds in amount of invoice on this product type and adding it to the basket. You can also add custom attributes for them for example add in invoice number.

In Magento it is also possible to add custom design to each product page so that you can style it to look more like an 'invoice payment'. That way you can use a more standard Magento checkout.

Here's an example of what I mean: http://www.xtento.com/magento-services/pay-your-invoice-online.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, is this a http://www.xtento.com/magento-services/pay-your-invoice-online.html free extension? Can you provide me the link to download this , or is any other free extension for my requirements? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I've looked again on the link I provided to investigate further how they've done it. And it looks like they've used custom options on a simple product. Don't think they've used an extension however it looks like they've done some custom JS changes to make the unit price update based on the Custom Option field. My advise would be to speak to them and see if they can shed any further light on it. Alternatively look at their JS in the source code of that page.

Comment: hi, sure.... i will try to speak with them. please be with me for next few days. I really need your help if they don't help me.

Comment: no problem, just let me know